# Convert .PPT (2007-x) to JPEG/GIF in Linux

Tags: php, linux, shell, powerpoint, jpeg

I am having problems finding a solution to convert **Powerpoint documents to JPEG**.

> - **Imagick** is not able to handle .PPT
> - So I used **unoconv**, which handles .ppt files, but only up to ppt.(97/2003/XP) **not** 2007 altough it say input yes. It tells me that it cannot handle the source.

Is there a commandline solution or library, that is able to do that ?

PS: unoconv is based on openoffice lib.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that actually a quote? If so, where from?

Comment: I get error: UNO IllegalArgument during import phase: Source file cannot be read. URL seems to be an unsupported one.
http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/unoconv under "Präsentationsformate" it says Input OK

Comment: Also here : http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Framework/Article/Filter/FilterList_OOo_3_0.  "Microsoft PowerPoint 2007 XML Template". Conversion from PDF to JPEG works. But not when using PPT to JPEG. I tried to create an .PPT (2003) with OpenOffice but it also fails to read the source.

Comment: `unoconv --version unoconv 0.5
Written by Dag Wieers <dag@wieers.com>
Homepage at http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/

platform posix/linux2
python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jun 18 2012, 14:10:23) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)]
LibreOffice 3.4`

Comment: I have updatet libreOffice to 3.6 error `unoconv pptxp.ppt
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
JavaVM: JNI_CreateJavaVM called _exit, caught by abort_handler in javavm.cxx
[Java framework] sunjavaplugin.soCan not create JavaVirtualMachine, abort handler was called.
[Java framework] sunjavaplugin.soCan not create Java Virtual Machine
[Java framework] sunjavaplugin.soCan not create Java Virtual Machine
[Java framework] sunjavaplugin.soCan not create Java Virtual Machine
Error: Unable to connect or start own listener. Aborting.`

Comment: It just worked with one old ppt. I just tried the command 3 times and it worked then. The developer page says : " if it fails try again, sometimes it does not work." Still need a more reliable solution

Answer (score 0):

First try using unoconv v0.6, and make sure you read the README which has lots of tips to troubleshoot problems. Often issues are caused because e.g. not all required packages have been installed for a specific document format, or an existing office process is causing errors.

The troubleshooting section should be the first thing to look at:

- https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv#troubleshooting-instructions

Comment: Thanks. I already managed to get it working after rebooting 3 times... very random. I am currently trying to execute unoconv from PHP exec(unoconv... ), since it is a py file. Do you also have a PHP Wrapper for unoconv? Thanks. Still great converter.

Comment: Is it possible to convert my ppt file (10 slides) to png? It only outputs the first slide when doing this. I tried using -e PageRange parameter, but still only the first page. I need myppt.ppt => myppt1.png, myppt2.png etc. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try [JODConverter](https://github.com/mirkonasato/jodconverter) and a recent version of OpenOffice.